# OAuth Client Authorization Server behind proxy

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm using the `spring-security-oauth2-client` libary and I'm struggling to get the Authentication Request redirect location to work correctly when I want my frontend application to access the authorization server behind a proxy.

I have exposed my frontend application to the internet. But I don't want to expose any of my other infrastructure:

- Authorization Server (Keycloak)
- API Gateway (spring-cloud-gateway with spring-security-oauth2-client)
- Backend (spring-security-resource-server)

My frontend is a SPA hosted on a NGINX that is configured to proxy requests to the API Gateway and the authorization server.

I can configure two URL's the `redirect-uri` and the `authorization-uri`, but it seems only `redirect-uri` respects the "Forwarded" family of HTTP headers.

For instance:

```
curl api-gateway.example.com/oauth2/authorization/keycloak --header "Forwarded: host=frontend.example.com"

# Response:
Satus = 302
Location = https://authorization-server.example.com/auth?response_type=code&client_id=api-gateway&redirect_uri=https://frontend.example.com/login/oauth2/code/keycloak...
```

Note the api-gateway is respecting the forwarded header and sets the redirect URI to the frontend application.

I want the same behaviour for the authorization server URI. So that the response will be:

```
Satus = 302
Location = https://frontend.example.com/auth-server/auth?response_type=code&client_id=api-gateway&redirect_uri=https://frontend.example.com/login/oauth2/code/keycloak...
```

This will let me expose the frontend application to the internet only while hiding all other infrastructure.

Comment: Keycloak is behind the reverse proxy (nginx).

Comment: I have several frontend and backend (resource-servers) applications.
Like so:

frontend-1.example.com
frontend-2.example.com
api-gateway.example.com
authorization-server.example.com
backend-1-resource-server.example.com
backend-2-resource-server.example.com

All requests from frontend (SPA hosted by nginx) will be proxied through nginx -> api gateway -> resource-server.

API Gateway (oauth-client) relays tokens to backend server (resource-server).

Comment: > Then why you are calling your API gateway? curl api-gateway.example.com/oauth2/authorization/keycloak You should call your reverse proxy.


Sorry this was a simplification. Nginx is configured with auth_request module which will redirect unauthenticated user-agents to:

´frontend.example.com/api-gateway/oauth2/authorization/keycloak´

With correct forwarded headers.

Comment: The only application exposed to the internet is the frontend application.

When the user agent is redirected to the authorization server after triggering the oauth flow (GET /apigw/oauth2/authorization/keycloak), I need the response location to be frontend.example.com/auth-server/...

But instead i get the URL of the authorization server. 

When configuring the redirect URL in the spring boot oauth client I'm able to use the "{baseUrl}" parameter which then will respect the "Forwarded" family of headers. It seems that "authorizationUri" property does not support this.

Comment: The authorization-server is accessible from the frontend (nginx).

location /auth/realms { proxy_pass https://keycloak:8443; }

But the backend will redirect to the auth server url (keycloak.example.com). Instead of frontend.example.com/auth/realms/my-realm...

Comment: Do you know which property of application.yml.

I also want frontend-1.example.com to be redirected to:
frontend-1.example.com/auth/realms/my-realm

while frontend-2.example.com will be redirected to:
frontend-2.example.com/auth/realms/my-realm

When they both talk to the same backend

Comment: I'm able to make it work a for single frontend by setting:

`spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.authorization-uri=https://frontend-1.example.com/auth/realms/my-realm...`

But that will not work for frontend-2.

Comment: What about supplying "authorizationRequestCustomizer" which will respect "forwarded" family of headers in same manner as how the "redirectUrl" is created?

Comment: You could try it. See also https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-oauth-requests

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and helping out.

I will try.